# FileSaver.js is saving corrupt images

Tags: http, blob, filesaver.js

This was working fine and suddenly stopped working. I'm not sure what exactly changed.

I need to download multiple images via URLs.

I'm using the following code:
https://plnkr.co/edit/nsxgwmNYUAVBRaXgDYys?p=preview

```
$http({
  method:"GET",
  url:"imageurl"
}).then(function(response){

  saveAs(new Blob([response.data]), "image.jpg");

},function(err){

});
```

The files have different sizes, they are not 0 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

For others coming here, check [this solution](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/381).

What needed to be done was to add `responseType: "blob"` to the request:

```
$http({
  method:"GET",
  url:"imageurl",
  responseType: "blob"
})
.then(...)
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType) is the documentation for the `responseType` valid values, where it says the default is `""` so the response is treated as text:

> **""**: An empty responseType string is treated the same as "text", the **default type** (therefore, as a DOMString).
>
> **"blob:"**: The response is a Blob object containing the binary data.

Answer (score 0):

Following code worked for me:

```
axios.get(`http://localhost:61078/api/values`, {
  responseType: 'blob',
}).then(response => {
  if (response) {
    var FileSaver = require('file-saver');
    FileSaver.saveAs(new Blob([response.data]), "image.png");
  }
});
```